# PySpark RDD List Split by Delimeter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm super new to both Python and Spark and I'm trying to remove values within a `string` by a delimiter. I have an RDD with the following lines.

I'd like to remove everything before the '_' underscore and only keep the remaining value as a string. I tried using something like this below but failed. Any help would be awesome. Thank you and I apologize if I miss-worded anything being a noob.

```
a.split('_')
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

# Preferably Something Like This:
# Before
a = rdd.take(1)[1]
a
{u'bin1_11394071': 1, u'bin1_11052103': 1, u'bin1_11052101': 1}

# After
new_a.take(1)[1]
new_a
{u'11394071': 1, u'11052103': 1, u'11052101': 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your input to recreate the rdd, I have

```
rdd.take(2)
{u'bin1_11394071': 1, u'bin1_11052103': 1, u'bin1_11052101': 1}, {u'bin1_11847272': 1, u'bin1_999999': 1, u'None_11847272': 1}]

new_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x : {k.split('_')[1]:v for k,v in x.iteritems()})
new_rdd.take(2)
[{u'11394071': 1, u'11052101': 1, u'11052103': 1}, {u'999999': 1, u'11847272': 1}]
```

Here, second dict value has, 'bin1_11847272' ,'None_11847272', as keys. After we split and take just the numeric part, they have same value and dictionary can't have multiple occurrences of a key.That's why in new_rdd, we have only 2 values.  You have to come up with a logic to handle this.

Comment: Hey @Suresh, I tried the code above and it works when I use it on a single record, but I'd like to do this for every record in an RDD. I'll show code & error.

# Sample 1 Record of RDD to Test Function
a = rdd3.take(1)[0] # Test RDD of 1 Record
{u'bin1_11394071': 1, u'bin1_11052103': 1, u'bin1_11052101': 1}

# Your Function
new_a = {k.split('_')[1]:v for k,v in a.iteritems()}
{u'11394071': 1, u'11052101': 1, u'11052103': 1}

# Apply to Function Entire RDD (rdd3)
rdd4 = {k.split('_')[1]:v for k,v in rdd3.iteritems()}
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: I mentioned using my solution, after you have collected the rdd into list . to map them in rdd itself,need to know how the rdd is. can you post your rdd just with take(2) and not with take(1)[1].

Comment: here is rdd3.take(2) output:    [{u'bin1_11394071': 1, u'bin1_11052103': 1, u'bin1_11052101': 1}, {u'bin1_11847272': 10, u'bin1_999999': 1, u'None_11847272': 10}]

Comment: is there a way to keep that value as a string? Would that preserve both values being included? Thanks a lot for all the help! I'll give credit.

Comment: It's already in string format after the split. If you don't need the first part in that string, then why can't you combine the values.

Comment: I'm trying to represent each string as an action, so if the same action is presented multiple times I want to show that. Some of the values in the RDD actually have it aggregated as {'11394071':10} which means action 11394071 occurred 10 times.

Comment: the next step for me is, after removing the values before the underscore to then expand out the records that have multiple actions. So a record like this {'11394071':3} becomes {'11394071','11394071','11394071'}.